# problem with paths wordpress in subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, path

i moved kernel files wordpress to a subfolder

now have a folder "content" and "kernel" at root

and got some problems

some commands only work with subfolder "kernel"

for example...

i use this function for to add change time for name scripts and styles

```
function put_modified_time_version($src, $baseUrl){
    if ($src && strpos($src, $baseUrl) === 0) {
        $newSrc = remove_query_arg('ver', $src);
        $path = substr($newSrc, strlen($baseUrl));
        $path = wp_parse_url($path, PHP_URL_PATH);
        if ($mtime = @filemtime(untrailingslashit(ABSPATH) . $path)) {
            $src = add_query_arg('ver', $mtime, $newSrc);
        }
    }
    return $src;
}
add_filter('style_loader_src', 'modified_time_version_style', 15, 1);
function modified_time_version_style($src) {
    return ($src) ? put_modified_time_version($src, wp_styles()->base_url) : $src;
}
add_filter('script_loader_src', 'modified_time_version_script', 15, 1);
function modified_time_version_script($src) {
    return ($src) ? put_modified_time_version($src, wp_scripts()->base_url) : $src;
}
```

this works only for js and css in "kernel" folder

functions work from a folder "content"

think that a problem with `$url = substr($newSrc, strlen($baseUrl));`

tell me how it is better to specify it correctly so that everything would work?

Answer (score 0):

If `ABSPATH` isn't returning the right thing then try some others. If you want a different path than one related to the current file then define a constant in a file that has the correct path (e.g. the main plugin file) and use that constant instead. For example in your main plugin.php

```
define('INTERESTING_PATH', ABSPATH);
define('INTERESTING_PATH2', ABSPATH . '/content/');
define('INTERESTING_PATH3', WP_CONTENT_DIR);
define('SITE_ROOT', str_replace('wp-content', '', WP_CONTENT_DIR));
define('PLUGIN_STUFF', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
```

Then everywhere else in the code you can use the constants. For example

```
$fp = fopen( INTERESTING . "sitemap.xml", 'w' );
```

If you need a directory higher in the hierarchy then use `dirname($path)`. e.g. `define('WHATEVER', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));` or `define('WHATEVER', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/content/');`

Comment: thanks
 but it does not change anything
 functions work fine but only see  kernel files folder

Comment: If you need a directory higher in the hierarchy then use `dirname($path)`. e.g. `define('WHATEVER', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));` or `define('WHATEVER', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/content/');`

Answer (score 0):

as i wrote above

found a strange problem when transferring core files to a subfolder

for example...

function that adds versioning for js and css

this function adds versioning regardless of position of core files
problem was in `$baseURL` maybe it will be useful to someone

```
function version_asset( $src, $handle, &$deps ) {
    $path = parse_url( $src, PHP_URL_PATH );
    foreach ( $deps->default_dirs as $dir ) {
        if ( 0 === strpos( $path, $dir ) ) {
            return $src;
        }
    }
    $version = get_file_version( $src );
    $deps->registered[ $handle ]->ver = $version;
    return add_query_arg( 'ver', $version, $src );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', __NAMESPACE__ . '\version_script', 10, 2 );
function version_script( $src, $handle ) {
    global $wp_scripts;
    return version_asset( $src, $handle, $wp_scripts );
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', __NAMESPACE__ . '\version_style', 10, 2 );
function version_style( $src, $handle ) {
    global $wp_styles;
    return version_asset( $src, $handle, $wp_styles );
}
function get_file_version( $url ) {
    $content_url = content_url();
    $filepath    = str_replace( $content_url, WP_CONTENT_DIR, $url );
    $filepath    = explode( '?', $filepath );
    $filepath    = array_shift( $filepath );
    if ( ! file_exists( $filepath ) ) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        $timestamp = filemtime( $filepath );
    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
        return;
    }
    return $timestamp ? (string) $timestamp : null;
}
```